# Can't access container's web server on localhost:80

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I can't access container's web server on `localhost:80` however I can access the webserver on `127.0.0.1:80`.

What am I doing wrong?

I have docker Version 1.12.2-rc1-beta27 (build: 12496) installed on a Mac.

I ran a container with the command `docker run -d -p 80:80 training/webapp python app.py`.

The container has the following properties

```
$docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
baaf4676e548        training/webapp     "python app.py"     22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->5000/tcp   big_volhard
```

My understanding was I should be able to access the website from `localhost:80`.

This does not work. I get the error message

```
Could not get any response
```

I know that I am using Docker for Mac as I've ran the command `env | grep DOCKER` and it returns no output.

First update: My `/etc/hosts` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Second update: I've also noticed that when I run the containers using command `docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py`, then `localhost:autoGeneratedPortNumber` works.

Now I'm not sure why both commands (which are more or less the same, the only difference being in one the port number is being specified) have different effects.

Comment: If you edit `/etc/hosts` and add `127.0.0.1  localhost`, does it work?

Comment: @EldadAK My ```/etc/hosts``` has that already. I have updated the post to include how my host file looks like. I'm still having the issue.

Comment: Strange... I tried to run it on my mac, without any configuration changes and it worked both for 127.0.0.1 and localhost. So I assume something in your network environment is different...

Comment: @EldadAK I've just noticed that when I run the container using command ```docker run -d -P training/webapp python app.py```, then localhost:autoGeneratedPortNumber``` works. I'm not sure why both commands have different effects.

Comment: Ahh.. so this is it! I was adding `-p 80:5000` to the run command. Not sure why http://127.0.0.1/ will work with the auto generated IP. Might be a Docker feature?

Answer (score 1):

In your server file,
instead of listening your server at 127.0.0.1 (localhost), listen at 0.0.0.0
which means that your server will now listen to any available network interface.
I was making this mistake, but after changing it , it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IPv6. Your host file defines localhost to be the IPv6 address (the "::1" is an IPv6 syntax):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

And most likely you are on an IPv4 network where the IPv6 requests are ignored. Docker may also default to publishing on the IPv4 "0.0.0.0" wildcard interface when you don't specify an interface. The easiest solution is to stick with 127.0.0.1 with all your requests.